# Why 'use strict' doesn't let me write in file?

Tags: perl

Why does `use strict` not let me open and write in a file as in the code below? Commenting out `use strict` works perfectly.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = "file_abc.txt";
open($fh, '>', $filename) or die("Couldn't open $filename\n");
print $fh "ABC";
print $fh "DEF\n";
print $fh "GHI";
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `strict`, you typically declare each variable with `my`:

```
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die("Couldn't open $filename\n");
```

You can get more information about some error messages by using `use diagnostics;`:

```
Global symbol "$fh" requires explicit package name at ...
Execution of ... aborted due to compilation errors (#1)
    (F) You've said "use strict" or "use strict vars", which indicates 
    that all variables must either be lexically scoped (using "my" or "state"), 
    declared beforehand using "our", or explicitly qualified to say 
    which package the global variable is in (using "::").
```